# Javascript to add the value of a textbox to a listboxfor

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script type ="text/javascript">

    $(function() {
        $('#AddDirector').click(function () {
           $('#VideoLanguageDirector').append(
               new Option($('input[name=Director]').val()));
        });
    });    

</script>
```

```html
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBox("Director")
</div>
<div>
    <input type="button" name="AddDirector" value="Add Director" id="AddDirector" />
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedLanguage.VideoLanguageDirector, Model.SelectedLanguage.VideoLanguageDirector.Select(d => new SelectListItem() { Text = d.Name, Value = d.Name }))
</div>
```

What I want to do is have a textbox where you click "add" and the text in the textbox inserts into the `listboxfor`.

Right now the javascript event doesn't fire.

Comment: Looks like you are using jquery. Did you reference the library? What does the developer console say when you try to click it ?

Comment: Have you tried assigning the onclick() method inside of the <input> tag instead of registering the event with jquery?

Comment: I have added my entire script block with the reference. Still having the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you look into your developer tools in your browser.

I'm pretty sure your listbox isn't named `#VideoLanguageDirector`

I assume it's named `#SelectedLanguage.VideoLanguageDirector` and make sure you use the right jquery selector.

There is a difference between `#` and `.` the first being an ID-selector, the second a class-selector.

If you use `@Html.TextBox('Director')` it's the name of that textbox, not necessary the ID.

Could you verify all this?

Comment: This more or less was the answer. I had to name my ids a little better. Thanks.